# Observation about powers and copowers (in category theory)

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, adjoint-functors, functors, representable-functor

Suppose that the category $\mathbf C$ has powers and copowers of every object. Fixed a set $x$ one can define the functor $F:\mathbf C\to \mathbf C$, whose object function is $c\mapsto \coprod_x c$ (to be precise I should  write $\coprod_{i\in x} (c)_i$); dually one can define the functor $G:\mathbf C\to \mathbf C$, whose object function is $c\mapsto \prod_x c$. This functions extend functorially on the arrows, and one can prove that there is a bijection $\mathbf C(F-,-)\cong\mathbf C(-,G-)$ natural  in both  variables; it follows that $F\dashv G$.

Fixed an object $c$ in $\mathbf C$ one can also  define the functors $F':\mathbf {Set}\to \mathbf C$ extending $x\mapsto \coprod_x c$, and $G':\mathbf {Set}\to \mathbf C$ extending $x\mapsto \prod_x c$. One can prove that ${\mathbf C} (\coprod_x c,d) \cong \prod_x {\mathbf C}(c,d)$ naturally for every $d$ in $\mathbf C$ and set $x$. Also, fixed $x$ and letting $c$ vary in $\mathbf{C}$, using the functors defined in the first paragraph, the bijection above becomes natural in $c$ and $d$. These concepts all together confuse me a bit, can one say something general about this situation? I feel like there are some links that I am not seeing, but I have not really a precise question. Thanks for your patience

Comment: These are examples of (co)tensoring in the sense of enriched category theory.

Comment: "can one say something general about this situation" is not really a focused question, -1.

Comment: They are used in the geometric realization of a simplicial complex. You want to glue all the simplices according to their face and degeneracy maps, so you start by taking a disjoint union of as many versions of $\Delta^n$ as there are $n$-simplices. Maybe you'd like to look into this. Also they appear in the formula for pointwise Kan extensions.